# 2 instances of web app open

Tags: php, mysql

When a user clicks Forgot Password a token is created as a link to be sent in email.
User clicks the link, the token is checked in database for existence and expiry. All is well so a new password form is shown and the user enters a new password. It gets hashed, salted and stored in the user table. I have this sorted up to this point but what I cannot figure out is why I now have 2 instances of this web app open.
Is there some way to have the email link go back to original signup page without having to be opened in a new window?
My script is php and mysql.
My link looks like this:
http://www.mysite.com/resetpassword.php?token=$token

Comment: That will be because the user's email client has decided to open it in a new window; I don't think you'll be able to do much about that, unfortunately. About all I can think of is using javascript to close the original window once the reminder email has been sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control how the user opens the tabs of his applications.

If he clicked Forget Password in one tab, opened his email account in another, and opened your token link in a third, you cannot control it.

Comment: Thank you. I guess now I'll get to work on figuring how to close the original page so only 1 will be open.